# Regex range with backref

Tags: javascript, regex

Several days ago, as part of a game of regex golf, I was tasked with constructing a regex that matches strings whose characters are in strictly alphabetic order (repeats allowed).  For example, it should match

```
bet
fin
ghost
accjkkpppz
```

but should not match

```
aghast
polonium
rhesus
qispeha
```

failing on 'a', 'o', 'h', and 'i' respectively.

I first used `^a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$`but it occurred that a much shorter solution should be available using a backref:

```
^((.)(?=[\1-z]|$))+$
```

This regex should find a character, look ahead and see either a character >= it or the end of the work, and repeat.

However, I'm hung up with the backref and range in the middle which doesn't seem to work with any of the tests I've put it through:

`[\1-z]`

Is there any way to use a backreference in a range?

Comment: Nope, you can't use a backreference in a character class. Also, using regex with JS isn't the "best" choice for golfing. As the regex flavor in JS is quite limited compared to PCRE, perl or .NET ...

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but `better` should not match, since there is an `e` and `r` after the `t`.

Comment: ah, true.  how embarrassing.  I'll make the edit

Comment: For you strict examples, you can use [this](http://regex101.com/r/qB9xZ8). It won't work for all cases of course, but does for the specific ones, if that golf has specific test cases to pass.

Comment: actually, those were just examples I'd come up with to match the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official error that the JavaScript regex implementation should give, is:

`JavaScript does not support octal character escapes` for the `\1`

and `Literal hyphens in character classes must be escaped` for `-`

So basically, it thinks you are trying to escape the number `1`, which then makes it think tha the hyphen is also literal...

---

Due to the specific nature of your requirements, I think that your first regex is going to have to do.